# Branched output Keras

Tags: python, keras

My model is such that it branches into 2 output layers as follows:

Input -> L1 -> L2 -> L3 -> out1

Input -> L1 -> L2 -> L3 -> out2

I am using it this way because I want `out1` and `out2` to have 2 different activation functions. Therefore, I have created a model:

```
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out1, out2])
```

I am compiling it using:

```
model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-2), loss=[loss_fn1, loss_fn2], metrics=[accuracy])
```

loss functions are defined this way:

```
def loss_fn1(y_true, y_pred):
    #send channel 1 to get bce dice loss
    loss1 = binary_crossentropy(y_true[:, :, :, 0:1], y_pred[:, :, :, 0:1])   
    return loss1

def loss_fn2(y_true, y_pred):    
    #l2 loss for channels 2 and 3
    loss2 = mean_squared_error(y_true[:, :, :, 1:3], y_pred[:, :, :, 1:3])
    return loss2
```

Does this use `loss_fn1` on `out1` and `loss_fn2` on `out2` tensor? Because, that is what I intend to do, but I am unsure regarding whether my code actually does that. Any pointers would help.

I want to use `loss_fn1` on `out1` tensor and `loss_fn2` function on `out2` tensor.

EDIT:

loss value from loss_fn1 range: [0, 1] - sigmoid activation.

loss value from loss_fn2 range: [0, inf] - no activation

Is there a way to reduce loss_fn1 and loss_fn2 independently, without using separate models? I am afraid that loss1 + loss2 would eventually only cause a decrease in value of loss2 as loss1 has a low value in comparison to loss2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is right. From the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> If the model has multiple outputs, you can use a different loss on each output by passing a dictionary or a list of losses. The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses.

Comment: But, my loss value 1 is in the range [0, 1] and my loss value 2 can be any number, be it 500. How do I make sure the loss value 1 also decreases? Because, the sum of loss value 1 and 2 would be 500+1 = 501, wherein the contribution of loss value 1 is low, which means decreasing loss value 1 to 0 would only decrease the total loss to 500, which is insignificant. How would I deal with such an issue? Is there a way to reduce loss_fn1 and loss_fn2 independently?

Comment: To reduce the loss independently, you should probably define 2 separate models and alternate the training of them. In practice, you normally weight the losses to combat the scale problem. In Keras, this can be done with the `loss_weights` argument from compile

Comment: the `loss_weights` seems like a good idea to me. Do you have any experience with it? When one loss is [0, 1] while the other loss can go upto infinity. I could set the 'loss_weights` argument to `[1.0, 0.00001]`. Not sure what would be the right approach. I dont want to train separate models because I want the rest of the layers to have the same weights, because out1 and out2 are related.

Comment: How does the loss go up to infinity? For a "finite" loss in the range [0, 500], you could set the `loss_weights` coefficients to something like 1 and 1/500. Also, it is still possible to share weights with 2 different models. E.g. you could define `model1 = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out1])` and `model2 = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out2])`

Comment: Its a mean squared error loss, so there is no particular range defined. So, if I define `model1 = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out1])` and `model2 = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out2])` and train them alternately for every batch size, it should work, right? A better approach would be to have 2 models independently reducing loss functions and still be correlated with each other due to the shared weights, right?

Comment: Will give it a try!