# How to use a well trained model as input to another model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, deep-learning

I'll start with the code and after put my question.

```
model1_input= keras.Input(shape=(5,10))
x = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(model1_input)
model1_output = layers.Dense(4)(x)

model1= keras.Model(model1_input, model1_output, name='model1')
model1.summary()

//----

model2_input= keras.Input(shape=(5,10))
y = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(model2_input)
model2_output = layers.Dense(4)(y)

model2= keras.Model(model2_input, model2_output, name='model2')
model2.summary()

//----

model3_input= keras.Input(shape=(5, 10))
layer1 = model1(model3_input)
layer2 = model2(layer1)
model3_output = layers.Dense(1)(layer2)
model3= keras.Model(model3_input, model3_output , name='model3')
model3.summary()

model3.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model3.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

When execute this code, what will happen with the model 1 and model 2 weights? they would stay untrained?

I would like to use trained model1 and trained model2 predictions to train model3. Can I write something like that?

```
model1_input= keras.Input(shape=(5,10))
x = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(model1_input)
model1_output = layers.Dense(4)(x)

model1= keras.Model(model1_input, model1_output, name='model1')
model1.summary()

model1.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model1.fit(model1_inputs, model1_outputs, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

//----

model2_input= keras.Input(shape=(5,10))
y = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(model2_input)
model2_output = layers.Dense(4)(y)

model2= keras.Model(model2_input, model2_output, name='model2')
model2.summary()

model2.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model2.fit(model2_inputs, model2_outputs, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

//----

model3_input= keras.Input(shape=(5, 10))
layer1 = model1(model3_input)
layer2 = model2(layer1)
model3_output = layers.Dense(1)(layer2)
model3= keras.Model(model3_input, model3_output , name='model3')
model3.summary()

model3.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model3.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

I'm afraid when I train model3 this will change the already trained weights of models 1 and 2. In this case, what will happen with models 1 and 2 weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if keras works that way but even if it does it still will change the weights as long as the layers are trainable. Try freezing the layers. These links might help you [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059529/how-to-freeze-weights-in-certain-layer-with-keras),[2](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/).

Another option will be to branch the layers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774552/branched-output-keras).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll check these link. Seems to be a nice option freeze the layers.

Comment: A poorly way maybe is use models 1 and 2 to predict the outputs and use the result as model3's inputs for training.